# Vue Component Data doesn't update

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I need to create two components who share data. I making a item lists and item cart who add or delete the specified items.

HTML:

```
<script>
  var food_menu = '[{"cat":"Burgers","name":"Hamburger classic","text":"200g of meat with chips","price":"9,50"},{"cat":"Burgers","name":"Hamburger chili","text":"250g of meat with chips + drink (orange juice 0,5l)","price":"12,50"},{"cat":"Burgers","name":"Chickenburger","text":"250g of meat with chips + drink (orange juice 0,5l)","price":"10,50"},{"cat":"Burgers","name":"Chickenburger chili","text":"250g of meat with chips + drink (orange juice 0,5l)","price":"14,50"},{"cat":"Steaks","name":"Baconburger","text":"300g of meat with chips","price":"16,50"},{"cat":"Steaks","name":"Hotburger","text":"300g of meat with chips + drink (orange juice 0,5l)","price":"18,50"},{"cat":"Maxs","name":"Hotburger max","text":"450g of meat with chips","price":"21,50"},{"cat":"Maxs","name":"Chickenburger max","text":"450g of meat with chips","price":"15,50"}]';

</script>

<body>
  <main>
      <cart></cart>
      <food :menu="menu"></food>
  </main>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
</body>
```

The cart component:

```
const cart = Vue.component('cart', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <pre>{{$data}}</pre>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      items: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$parent.$on("añadir", (item, index) => {
    alert('asdasd')
      if (typeof this.items[index] === "undefined") {
        this.items[index] = item;
        this.items[index].quantity = 1;
      } else {
        this.items[index].quantity++;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The item list component (It Works)

```
const food = Vue.component('food', {
  props: ['menu'],
  template: `
      <div>
        <div class="food-item" v-bind:class="item.cat" v-for="(item,index) in menu">
          <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
          <a class="add-cart" v-on:click="addToCart(item, index)">Añadir al carro</a>
          <p>{{item.text}}</p>
          <span>{{item.price}}€</span>
        </div>
    </div>
  `,
  methods: {
    addToCart(item, index) {
      this.$parent.$emit('añadir', item, index);
    }
  }
});
```

And the separated instances:

```
new Vue({
    el: 'main',
    data: {
      menu: JSON.parse(food_menu)
    },
    components: {
      'food': food,
      'cart': cart
    }
  });
```

When i try to modify "items" it doesnt change the template.

https://jsfiddle.net/50l3r/wu0gjz2r/6/

Comment: You might want to try using events instead of letting children mess with the items array directly.

Comment: I dont understand u

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events

Comment: @hayavuk i updated the code

Comment: I've played with your code a little, and I see what the problem is. First of all it's not `this.$parent.$emit`, but just `this.$emit`. Secondly, since the items and the cart are unrelated, one cannot trap events from the other. You should either put the items inside the cart component (e.g., using slots, etc), or you should learn how to use Vuex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find the problem posting on vue forums: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-component-data-doesnt-update/20086

Problem caused because i can't modify array like this:

```
this.items[index] = newValue
this.items.length = newLength
```

I need to use:

```
Vue.set(this.items, index, newValue)
```

or

```
this.items.push()
this.items.splice()
```

Link to docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats